# Accessing a HashMap of custom objects in request scope after a redirect

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have a `HashMap` of custom objects being passed to a JSP using `RequestDispatcher` and I am able to access the object and its properties using JSTL.

However the code fails in case the parameter is sent using `response.sendRedirect()` .

I am not sure what the reason is and how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The `response.sendRedirect()` basically instructs the client (the webbrowser) to send a **new** request on the given URL. You'll also see this being reflected by a change in the browser address bar.

A **new** request does of course not contain the attribtues of the previous (or any other) request. That would otherwise have broken the whole concept of "request scope".

To preprocess a GET request, you need to do the job in `doGet()` method of a servlet and then redirect to the URL of that servlet instead.

E.g.

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/foo");
```

and

```
@WebServlet("/foo")
public class FooServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Map<String, Foo> foos = fooService.map();
        request.setAttribute("foos", foos);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/foo.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Note that this problem is in **no way** related to having a hashmap of custom objects in the request scope.

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score 0):

You can not share a request attribute in response.sendRedirect as it creates a new request.

But, if you want that HashMap, in response.sendRedirect, you can put that in session like

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("myMap", [HashMap object]);
```

and can share between the servlet and JSP. This works in both RequestDispatcher and sendRedirect.

Comment: Note that this may lead to undesired webapp behaviour and bad user experience when the map contains request scoped data instead of session scoped data. Putting request scoped data in the session scope would expose it over multiple browser tabs/windows in the same session.

Comment: Thats true but when the requirement forces to share data across pages, we have to put that map in the session.

Comment: I am new to Java, however as far as I know, for each request, the container(for eg: Tomcat) creates a new thread and kills it soon after it is processed. So in this redirect case, I think the first request's thread gets killed soon after calling response.sendRedirect(). So how do we get the resource(HashMap in this case), which is no longer existent, in the next request (redirected request) ?

Comment: @user1089770 If you observer the statement, we are placing the HashMap in session and not in request. Session will be same and  lasts across multiple requests (multiple pages) until a user action OR server destroys it. Due to this behaviour, you can get HashMap object in the next request too.